# Input shape error while building 2D-CNN from 1D data: Keras

Tags: keras

I have a data matrix of size 100-by-50 (100 50D-features) from say 5 classes. I am treating each feature as a image (1-by-50 pixels) by reshaping the data matrix as

```
X=X.reshape(X.shape[0],1,X.shape[1],1)
```

Hence, my input shape will be

```
inpshape= (1,1, X.shape[1])
```

Next, I define a CNN as

```
# build model
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',input_shape=inpshape ))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
.
.
.
```

However I am getting error

```
Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2
```

Is my treatment of 1D data as 2D wrong?
If yes how can I implement 1D conv network instead with my data.

---

----------------------Update-------------------------------------
Here is the code I wrote with just 1 conv layer:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam

num_labels = y.shape[1]
X=X.reshape(X.shape[0],1,X.shape[1],1) 
inpshape= (1,1, X.shape[1])
print(X.shape)

# build model
model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 3), padding='same',input_shape=inpshape ))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(300))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_labels))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'],optimizer='Adam')
```

Error: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2

Comment: Why do you want to use a 2D-Convolution? Using (3,3) filter size does not give you any additional information compared to (1,3) , if your dimension is already 1.

Comment: @McLawrence (3,3) is just a number. I want to understand the error. Even (1,3) doesn't work. I even tried Conv1D layers on my data but again one or other input error occurs. I am trying 2D, as I read ID conv are programmed to handle sequential data better like time series prediction.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, using your given your input shape and the layers you named. Can you please post your whole model configuration. Which version of `keras` are you on? Your `inshape` does not match the shape you use in the first line. You swapped the `1` and `X.shape[1]`. However, this gives me another error on version `2.0.8`.

Comment: Could you provide us with a full code? Maybe the error is in a different place.

Comment: @McLawrence I am on python 3.6, keras 2.0.6 with tensorflow backend

Comment: Can you share code, how you generate your dataset? You still have to change your `inpshape` from `(1,1, X.shape[1])` to `(1, X.shape[1], 1)`.

Comment: @McLawrence changing the input shape didn't worked either (same error). My dataset is 50-D mfcc feature extracted from audio files, that makes my data matrix no_examples-by-50. But you can generate any random 2D matrix and help me resolve the error

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make sure you have initialized the model before adding the layers `model= Sequential()`

Looks like you are adding  layers to an already trained model.